# Sort string containing combination of characters, period and number in descending order in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a string field in descending order.

Rules for sorting:

- 'P' and 'S' will remain constant all the time
- Nulls should be last
- The entire character needs to be sorted in descending order starting with first preference order to the chars before 'P' , then the chars after 'P' and finally followed by chars after S.
- The chars before P should be sorted in descending like a decimal number , highest first ex - 4.5,4.2,3.9 and they decide the main order.
- If the chars before 'P' are same then it should use the chars between 'P' and 'S' as the second preference order and sorted as a number , highest first.
- If the chars before and after 'P' are same then the chars after 'S' should be considered for sorting as number ,highest first.

Sample source data:

```
3.9P2S1
4.0P5S1
3.10P4S1
3.11P2S3
3.7P2S1
3.2P10S1
4.0P4S1
3.5P2S1
4.0P16S1
3.12P6S1
3.12P10S2
3.14P3S2
```

Expected output:

```
4.0P16S1
4.0P5S1
4.0P4S1
3.14P3S2
3.12P10S2
3.12P6S1
3.11P2S3
3.10P4S1
3.9P2S1
3.7P2S1
3.5P2S1
3.2P10S1
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but I am not able to get the desired output.

```
with firmware_name as (
select '3.9P2S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '4.0P5S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.10P4S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.11P2S3' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.7P2S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.2P10S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '4.0P4S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.5P2S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '4.0P16S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.12P6S1' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.12P10S2' as firmware from dual union all
select '3.14P3S2' as firmware from dual)
select * from firmware_name
order by to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '^\d+')) desc nulls last,
to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '^\d+\.(\d+)', 1, 1, null, 1)) desc,
regexp_replace(firmware, '\d+\.\d+') desc;
```

According to the above '4.0P5S1' is the highest which is clearly wrong. Am not able to sort the last part. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `regexp_substr()`:

```
order by
     to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '^[^P]+')) desc nulls last,
     to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, 'P([^S]+)', 1, 1, '', 1)) desc,
     to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '[^S]+$')) desc
```

The first expression captures characters at the beginning of the string until a `'P'` is met (excluded). The second captures everything after `'P'` until a `'S'` is met. The final expression captures everything after the last `'S'`.

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer my question, really appreciate it... this worked for the most part but while checking, the values in the bottom 3.12P10S2 and 
3.12P6S1 were not sorted correctly. 3.12P6S1  was sorted higher then 3.12P10S2.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
order by 
   to_number(regexp_replace(firmware, 'P.+$')) desc nulls last,
   to_number(regexp_replace(firmware, '^.+P(\d+)S.+$', '\1')) desc,
   to_number(regexp_replace(firmware, '^.+S')) desc
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, this works flawlessly! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following, where you use the same regex, but different occurrence number:

```sql
order by 
    to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '[^PS]+', 1, 1)) desc,
    to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '[^PS]+', 1, 2)) desc,
    to_number(regexp_substr(firmware, '[^PS]+', 1, 3)) desc
```

Comment: thanks much for your reply. this works flawlessly , I have tested it with multiple value and works perfect. This is great. Thanks again